# What's the difference between importing a whole module vs importing just the required method from the module in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

When using scikit learn or other similar Python libraries, what's the difference between doing:

```
import sklearn.cluster as sk
model = sk.KMeans(n_clusters=n)
```

And

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
model = KMeans(n_clusters=n)
```

Is there any advantage to using one way over the other?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.
This is covered well in the Python documentation and many texts, both hard-copy and on line.

Comment: As explained [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function/187471) "*Importing the module doesn't waste anything; the module is always fully imported*" so there is no way to import *only* a specific thing from a module

Comment: @Prune from **how to ask**: "Examples: Good: Why does using float instead of int give me different results when all of my inputs are integers?" -- why is my question in a different category than the example?

Comment: I think this is a fine question. Sure, the issue is well-documented and there's a similar question on another SE site but it's also a well-worded question with concise and clear examples.

Comment: Good enough -- objection withdrawn.  I'll leave my comment as a bad example with good correction.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your first example, you've made the module `sklearn.cluster` accessible as `sk` and you can refer to its members accordingly. In your second example, you've only imported one member of `sklearn.cluster`, `KMeans`, so only that one is accessible. That's the difference.

As for advantages? Do whichever makes your code easier to read.

Comment: "*you've only imported one member ... so only that one is accessible*" I'd be careful with that wording. They've actually imported the *entire module*, it's just that only `kMeans` is *accessible*

Comment: It might be a matter of semantics. Yes, the whole module is loaded (as can be seen from `sys.modules`) but I was referring to the `import` keyword.